# sed unterminated `s' command in subprocess.call

Tags: python, scripting, sed, subprocess

I have to use python's subprocess.call module for this script.  I need look in a file for the following string:

```
"absolute/path/to/your/lib"
```

and replace it with the following:

```
/var/www/twiki/lib
```

My script is below, but when I run it, I get the output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 59: unterminated `s' command
```

Here's my command using python's subprocess.call module:

```
subprocess.call(['sed', '-e', 's/\"absolute\/path\/to\/your\/lib\/\"\/var\/www\/twiki\/lib\/', '\/var\/www\/twiki\/lib\/LocalLib.cfg'])
```

[UPDATE]

Here's the fixed code:

```
subprocess.call(['sed', '-e', 's/\"\/absolute\/path\/to\/your\/lib\"/\/var\/www\/twiki\/lib\//', '/var/www/twiki/bin/LocalLib.cfg'])
```

In the end, I was missing a few slashes and needed to double slash one of them.  Couldn't have figured it out without the community.

Comment: @Farahadix I changed the -i option to -e, but the error is still the same.  Thanks for the quick feedback!

Comment: You need a / before the terminating ' of your s command. You can also do s?...?...?

Comment: You have a `/` missing at the end of `lib`.

Comment: I just updated the command to reflect adding a `/` at the end of lib (in two locations.  The changes progressed me past `char 55` to `char 59` now.  But still, `unterminated s'` command.

Comment: FIXED!!  Thanks a ton to everybody!!  You got me on the right track!  I've updated the code to reflect what works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subprocess.call(['sed', '-e', 's/\"absolute\/path\/to\/your\/lib\/\"\/var\/www\/twiki\/lib\/', '\/var\/www\/twiki\/lib\/LocalLib.cfg'])
```

looks absolutely creepy.

First thing: why did you escape the `/`s on the file name argument? That is only necessary in the `s` command.

Second thing: If I replace your separator character from `/` to e.g. `#`, I can omit all the unnecessary escaping.

I did both and then got

```
subprocess.call(['sed', '-e', 's#"absolute/path/to/your/lib/"/var/www/twiki/lib/', '/var/www/twiki/lib/LocalLib.cfg'])
```

and what do I see? There are no `#` (i.e., no unescaped `/`) in the command.

Try

```
's#"absolute/path/to/your/lib/"#/var/www/twiki/lib/#'
```

here, or if you insist on using `/`, do

```
's/"absolute\/path\/to\/your\/lib\/"/\/var\/www\/twiki\/lib\//'
                                  ^                          ^
```

with `/`s added on the `^` marked places.

Edit: I changed the `"` positions in order to reflect the clearance of my misunderstanding. See the comments below.

Comment: `'\"' == '"'` in [Python string literal](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). `sed` don't need the quotes `"` to be escaped: `call(['sed', '-i', 's#"/old/path/"#/new/path/#', filename])`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, changed my answer.

Comment: the quote should be in the old path

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am not sure about that. I interpret the situation as if the path in the file is prepended by a `"`, and so should the new one be. Of course, the old path might be enclosed in `"` on both sides, while the new one shouldn't, but I rather think my original interpretation is correct.

Comment: the question is clear (look at the string after *"the following string:"* and *"the fixed code:"*)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ouch. Didn't see that; will fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is use a raw string notation, notice the "r" before the string in example below.

```
import subprocess

COMMAND = r"""
    mysql -u root -h localhost -p --exec='use test; select 1, 2, 3 | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > sample.csv
"""

proc = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
std_out, std_err = proc.communicate()
```

Though this works, I did this only because there were loads of these commands in the bash that I wanted to wrap it with python. I would prefer using mysql directly from python and using the csv module.